# JavaScript function.toString() doesn't produce the same result in jest than browser

Tags: javascript, npm, jestjs

I am trying to write a unit test for a function which get the parameter names. My function works fine but I am not able to test it with default parameters. I identified the bug as **function.toString()** doesn't produce the same result in Jest than inside browsers.

Does anyone know how to avoid this difference ?

```js
function testing(param1, param2 = 1) {}

let str = testing.toString();

// In browser console (Chrome, Firefox, Opera) I got the right code
// str = "function testing(param1, param2 = 1) {}"

// In Jest I got this 
// str = "function testing(param1) {var param2 = arguments.length > 1 && arguments[1] !== undefined ? arguments[1] : 1;}"
```

Comment: Jest has used Babel to convert the function to older syntax. It replaced the default argument value with code that calculates it.